# Android webview - XMLHttpRequest cannot load Origin <url> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, webview, cross-domain

I've an application which loads a complete website in the android webview. The native code in in the android project interacts with the webpage & vice-versa using the Android Jockey Library.

Everything works fine accept at one state I encounter the `XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... Origin <url> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error. This happens when the website (that gets loaded in the webview) makes an ajax call to the back-end api.

my website is at `m.mywebsite.com` which makes an ajax call to `api.mywebsite.com` - notably two separate sub-domains, but this seems to work fine on iOS.

I'm testing this on Android v4.4.2. Have tested it by compiling agains target sdk 15 and 19 but no difference.

I've applied most of the settings to my webview as follows:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + webView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
    }

    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setInitialScale(0);
```

And following is my jockey integration:

```
if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
        jockey = JockeyImpl.getDefault();
        jockey.configure(webView);
        webViewClient = new MyWebViewClient(this);
        jockey.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        setJockeyEvents();
        webView.loadUrl(EnvironmentManager.getStartUpURL());
    }
```

Anybody facing similar issue or have a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, where you able to resolve this?? We are trying to change the origin header for http and websocket calls from System WebView. So I think we have the same problem then you, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Hi I think you need to set a setting for you web view. Actually this issue come with the devices greater than API level 16. Find the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve this by sending an appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from the page on `api.mywebsite.com` like so:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://m.mywebsite.com
```

Comment: Just to confirm - do you mean sending this header in the request from `m.mywebsite.com` while making request to `api.mywebsite.com` or you mean the other way round?

Comment: I mean the other way round - sending the header in the response from api.mywebsite.com to m.mywebsite.com.